# Supressing a field if it begins with a letter in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to hide a field when another field starts with a letter. Just having trouble with the correct syntax in the formula.I tried this but no go

```
{FG10.ITEM_NUMB} LIKE '{A% - Z%}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the suppression formula box enter something like:

```
if left({FG10.ITEM_NUMB},1) in MakeArray("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z") then true;
```

There might be a regular expression way to do this. I will research that.